# AWGN channel in VHDL testbench

Tags: vhdl, testbed

I want to create AWGN channel in VHDL testbench. Is it possible? and how can I proceed? I searched online but not many related posts.

Regards

Comment: Have you noticed that **all** of your questions at StackOverflow have received a negative voting average? You should really improve your question quality. Please read ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in this question :) It's a valid question, and I think didn't asked before.

Comment: To begin, you don't explain what a "AWGN channel" is. And then: what did you try so far? What sources did you check? Where do you want to use it for. And so on, and so on: there are many more things. Did you read my link?

Comment: Yes, I did, will be careful next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

How to generate a uniform distributed value in VHDL is described [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.nl/2013/08/generating-random-numbers-in-vhdl.html). Quote (original by "Vipin Lal"):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity rand_gen is end rand_gen;

architecture behavior of rand_gen is 
    signal rand_num : integer := 0;
begin
    process
        variable seed1, seed2: positive;               -- seed values for random generator
        variable rand: real;   -- random real-number value in range 0 to 1.0  
        variable range_of_rand : real := 1000.0;    -- the range of random values created will be 0 to +1000.
    begin
        uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);   -- generate random number
        rand_num <= integer(rand*range_of_rand);  -- rescale to 0..1000, convert integer part 
        wait for 10 ns;
    end process;
end behavior;
```

Then you have to scale the output of the uniform function to a AWGN distribution. An example in C is given [here](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showcode/311.php). Quote(summarized from original by "Dr Cagri Tanriover")

```c
temp2 = ( rand() / ( (double)RAND_MAX ) );
temp1 = cos( ( 2.0 * (double)PI ) * rand() / ( (double)RAND_MAX ) );
result = sqrt( -2.0 * log( temp2 ) ) * temp1;
```

Just *correctly* convert this to VHDL. The `math_real` library contains all functions and constants required.